# Howto setup a DNS server cluster using 3 nameservers?

Tags: php, linux, domain-name-system, bind

I want to setup 3 DNS servers for my domains and i have no idea how to do that. I want the dns servers to function as the nameservers for my domains. I've done some research and i found the following:

- If you want to setup a DNS server *"BIND DNS Server"* is your way to go.
- If you want to setup a cluster of servers make sure at least one of them is in a different datacenter.
- If you want to use a webinterface to configure the zonefiles you can use [PRObind](http://probind.org/) or [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/standard.html). (prefering PRObind because webmin has a lot of other stuff i don't need)

  [image: Dns master slave example]

It seems like an easy task but it isn't. That's because there are a lot of tutorials on how to configure the master server. But almost nothing on how to create the slave servers. You also don't get much information  on how to manage the zones from a control panel on another server. My control panel is written in php and that's the main reason why i want my own dns servers. That is to give the client and me more control.

**Here's a summery of my questions:**

1. What linux OS distribution should i use for Bind?
2. Any tips, tricks or tutorials on how to configure master/slave servers?
3. What webinterface should i use?
4. Is there any API for Bind or a library already written that i can use on my control panel(php) ?

---

Any tips or suggestions are always welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid can i migrate this question automaticly to serverfault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Actually all linux distributions have bind, for you - depends on your policy, what are your other linux servers
2. Check BIND official manual
3. Choose what you like more, both are fine - you can remove additional modules from webmin
4. It's possible to use database for storing records (SDB API), more complex will be available in v10 (in development)